# hibernate criteria group Query is wrong

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to generate the following query using Criteria:

```
select order_number, order_date, sum(order_amount)
from st_pur_orders
group by ORDER_NUMBER,ORDER_DATE;
```

Here is my Criteria:

```
  Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(StPurOrders.class);
            cr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("orderNumber"), "orderDate")
                    .add(Projections.sum("orderAmount"))
                    .add(Projections.groupProperty("orderNumber"))
                    .add(Projections.groupProperty("orderDate")));
            cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(PurOrderColl.class));
            list = cr.list();
```

But the query getting generate in the background is this:

```
select this_.ORDER_NUMBER as y0_, sum(this_.ORDER_AMOUNT) as y1_,
    this_.ORDER_NUMBER as y2_, this_.ORDER_DATE as y3_
from STOCK.ST_PUR_ORDERS this_
group by this_.ORDER_NUMBER, this_.ORDER_DATE;
```

My Question is why is the `ORDER_NUMBER` field being listed twice?

Comment: Are you getting a correct result set, or is duplicate data actually appearing in your results?

Comment: There is actually Duplicate data appearing in my Results and so I am unable to map to PurOrderColl class since I have only three properties there.

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException your Criteria  already has `Projections.groupProperty("orderNumber")`. I don't see a need for `Projections.property("orderNumber"),`. Can you please remove that and try.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I actually removed both of them, orderNumber and orderDate and Now I have Something I can work with: `select sum(this_.ORDER_AMOUNT) as y0_, this_.ORDER_NUMBER as y1_, this_.ORDER_DATE as y2_ from STOCK.ST_PUR_ORDERS this_ group by this_.ORDER_NUMBER, this_.ORDER_DATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Question is why is the ORDER_NUMBER field being listed twice?

Your Criteria already has `Projections.groupProperty("orderNumber")`. So the generated query will include `orderNumber` in its select clause.

I don't see a need for specifying `Projections.property("orderNumber")` explicitly. Can you please remove that and try.

Same applies for any other field that is specified using `groupProperty(..)`.

Comment: Looks Like I actually need to remove the whole of this line `.add(Projections.property("orderNumber"), "orderDate")` and it worked.

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException That is true. Infact, once we include specify `groupProperty(...)` it is automatically included in the select clause. Updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this insight.